# Navigation styling change with jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on a navigation bar and wanted to mark the current page with its navigation item with class="active-link" so I can add a specific styling indicating which page you are on. However, when I use the below jquery code, it adds the class to all three navigation items at once when you are on the homepage ("/").

How can I make sure that on the homepage with URL "/" it only adds the class to the navigation item for "Home".

```
<nav>
  <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="/groups">Groups</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="/deals">Deals</a>
</nav>
```

```
<script>
    $(function() {
  $('nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active-link');
});
</script>
```

This is where I found the original code:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url/

Comment: This issue is addressed in the comments of your article:  `let current_location = location.pathname.split('/')[1]; if (current_location === "") return;`

Comment: $(function() {
    if ((location.pathname.split("/")[1]) !== ""){
        $('nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active-link');
    }
    else {
    $('nav .home-link').addClass('active-link');
    }
});

Is this a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

`a[href^="/"]` Selects every anchor tag whose href attribute value begins with "/". So, when you are at homepage, it will match all URLs. You should change it from `a[href^="/"]` to `a[href="/"]` (operator change from `^=` to `=`).
You script will look like this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
  $('nav a[href="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('active-link');
});
</script>
```

### Edit

As pointed out by **@freedomn-n**, It won't work for subpages. You will need to add additional logic for that.

Comment: Looks the same to me - can you be more descriptive as to what you've changed (edit: spotted the change, but it's so small needs some text)

Comment: This also won't work for sub pages, eg `/groups/myteam/summary`

Comment: @freedomn-m I have updated the answer and highlighted the change. Thanks.